# How to create database table in titanium by using model?

Tags: sqlite, titanium-alloy, database-abstraction

I have below 2 approach to create Db table in titanium.

**Approach 1** -- Create a sqlite database, using queries in the titanium code. like Ti.Database.open("DBName"); and then create tables using sqlite queries

```
var db = Ti.Database.open('DBName');

db.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)');
```

**Its working fine.**

But i need to know how to create table by using model

**Approach 2** -- Create database Ti.Database.open("DBName");

Create model book.js and here is the code

```
exports.definition = {
    config: {


        "columns": {
            "id":"TEXT PRIMARY KEY",
            "title":"TEXT  ",
            "author":"TEXT",
        },

        adapter: {
            type: "sql",
            collection_name: "book"
        }
    },
    extendModel: function(Model) {
        _.extend(Model.prototype, {
            // extended functions and properties go here
        });

        return Model;
    },
    extendCollection: function(Collection) {
        _.extend(Collection.prototype, {
            // extended functions and properties go here
        });

        return Collection;
    }
};
```

Now I am in little bit confusion for creating table using model.

Please help and guide me for creating table.

Answer (score 4):

If the adapter type="sql" then your DB is automatically created.

If you're using models, you no longer need to worry about opening the DB etc.

From the [Alloy_Collection_and_Model_Objects](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Alloy_Collection_and_Model_Objects), create a model and save it to DB:

```
var book = Alloy.createModel('book', {title:'Green Eggs and Ham', author:'Dr. Seuss'}); 
book.save();
```

To load data back from the DB:

```
var books = Alloy.Collections.instance('books');
var filteredArray = books.where({book_id: args.bookId});
```

Study the [Alloy_Collection_and_Model_Objects](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Alloy_Collection_and_Model_Objects) and the [Backbone JS docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/backbone/0.9.2/#Collection)